# Xcode energy gauges stopped working

Tags: ios, xcode

I've seem to have encountered a bug in Xcode where the energy gauges for my project have stopped working (they were working before). I'm testing on a device but whenever I select the energy tab on the debug session no information gets tracked and the energy usage reported is 0%.

Has anybody else encountered this error and found a workaround?

Here's an image for your reference:
[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: From Hitesh Boricha: Check out [Mac Developer Library: Using Debug Gauges](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-debug_navigator/articles/using_debug_gauges.html)

Comment: Thanks, I've already gone through the  documentation for Debug Gauges and it does not help my situation. I think I'll be raising a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I am seeing the same thing

Comment: I stopped having this issue with the latest versions of Xcode, but you have to ensure you're testing on a device.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this issue was resolved after I did "Reset All Settings" on the device.